# How to change selected item property in ListView

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I need to change selected item property in ListView(Xamarin Forms).

```
List<Item> _source = new List<Item>();
_source.Add(new Item { Title = "First item" });

ListView.ItemsSource = _source;
```

I'm trying to change the item property I've selected in the list.

```
Item item = ListView.SelectedItem as Item;
item.Title = "Changed title";
```

Tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I'm also trying to select an item with an index. Since the SelectedIndex property is missing I have tried to do so:

```
int selector = 1;
ListView.SelectedItem = _source[selector];
```

But it didn't work out either.

Help me please.
Thank you.

Comment: your Item class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I new on Xamarin Forms, I don't know about INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: INPC is a c# data binding concept, it has nothing to do specifically with XF.  There are thousands of articles available online that will show you how to implement it

Comment: Thank you. I try to find that.

Comment: @Jason is it good to make model class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jason said, you need to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface for Item class if you want to change Item property firstly.

```
 public class Item:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _Title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _Title; }
        set
        {
            _Title = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModelBase is the class that implementing **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then I suggest you can use **ObservableCollection** to replace List, because Observablecollection represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Finally, using binding for ListView and change selecteditem property.

```
<StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listview1" ItemsSource="{Binding source}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="btn1_Clicked"
            Text="update data" />
    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page18 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> source { get; set; }
    public Page18()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        source = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
        {
            new Item(){Title="title 1"},
            new Item(){Title="title 2"},
            new Item(){Title="title 3"},
            new Item(){Title="title 4"},
            new Item(){Title="title 5"}
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Item item = listview1.SelectedItem as Item;
        item.Title = "Changed title";
    }
}
```

About Binding and INotifyPropertyChanged, please take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: Thank you for helping☺️

Comment: @WinSoft If my reply solve your problem, please remember to mark my reply as answer, it is beneficial to others to find this answer, thanks.